# Conditionally returning a constant if function returns Undefined

Tags: function-construction, conditional

Often times functions might return `Undefined` in Mathematica, e.g. when the `Volume@RegionIntersection` is called for 2 objects which have no overlapping volume. A simple `If` statement checking if the return has been indeed `Undefined` does not seem to work. For example, `a=Undefined; If[a == Undefined, Print["yes"]]` ends up printing the command itself.

- How can we check if a variable (or a function return) such as `a` has been assigned as `Undefined` and assign a different value to it in that case?

Comment: Can you show a simple version of your function that returns Undefined?

Comment: You might want to use `RegionDisjoint` on the two regions before trying to compute the intersection.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks, indeed I should be checking for that in the first place, but to save computational time (as my current intersection detection routine is already very slow, this is about the post I mentioned to you earlier), I skipped checking for disjointness beforehand.

Comment: @bills MassDefect have provided one such example in their answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `SameQ` (===).

```
Volume[RegionIntersection[Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Circle[{2, 2}, 1]]] === Undefined
(* True *)
```